# Why is my_task.delay() working from shell but not apache/wsgi

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

Celery worker and beat are working fine.

Site loads fine except when I call a url that passes a task to Celery.

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ada.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my WSGI file.

```py
import os
import sys

import dotenv
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

dotenv.load_dotenv()

def addpath(path):
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)


addpath('/opt/ada')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ada.settings'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/opt/ada'
os.environ['CELERY_LOADER'] = "django"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

celery_config.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ada.settings')

app = Celery('ada')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from ada.celery_config import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app', )
```

I don't understand this error.

```sh
mod_wsgi (pid=2547): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/ada/ada/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ada/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'tasks'
```

Also, I can try and call the same task from the shell and it works.

The problem only manifests when calling a url that and so must be related to my apache2 site conf file, wsgi.py, or something related

What am I missing?

Comment: How does your `manage.py` script look? Do you do the same preparatory things there?

Comment: Yes. And would other non-celery-related tasks work if the wsgi was not correct? Nothing loads correctly if the wsgi is broken.

Comment: Can you share the `celery.py` file where you instantiate celery and set the configurations, etc?

Comment: I've added celery_config.py and __init__.py for reference.

Answer (score 1):

REMOVING the following line from `wsgi.py` fixes things.

```
os.environ['CELERY_LOADER'] = "django"
```

I do not know why it works and would love to understand.